# Difference between b=b++ and b++

Tags: java, post-increment

I was asked in an interview the below question.

```
int b = 0;
b = b++;
b = b++;
b = b++;
b = b++;
```

what will be the value of b after every line execution ?
The output is coming as 0 for every line.

Why is the output not coming as 0,1,2,3 ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Java, the expression

```
b = b++
```

is equivalent to

```
int tmp = b;
b = b + 1;
b = tmp;
```

Hence the result.

(In some other languages, the exact same expression has unspecified behaviour. See [Undefined behavior and sequence points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points).)

Answer (score 3):

Because this is the order of execution of `b = b++`:

1. Get the value of `b` into some temp (probably into a bytecode register); this is the first part of `b++`, since it's a *post*-increment
2. Increment and store the incremented result in `b` (the second part of `b++`)
3. Assign the value from Step 1 to `b` (the result of the `=`)

Comment: From what I see in byte code - `2: iload_1 m  3: iinc , 6: istore_1`  are called one after another. So, the value of `b` is first loaded into the stack (from the local variable array), then the value of b is fetched, incremented and written back to variable b. So, here b will be 1. then istore_1 is called which will pop the value of b from stack and overwrite the variable b (local variable array) with current value on stack (0).  So, in m particular implementation, at byte-code level itself, the values are being *overwritten* :)

Comment: @TheLostMind: Yes, first written in #2 above, then overwritten in #3 above. I suspect if it were a hotspot, HotSpot would...fix that...

Comment: What would the hot spot fix in this one?. I am merely curious. Will it *skip* the `iinc` ?

Comment: @TheLostMind: I don't know much about HotSpot's internals, but HotSpot's job is to make hotspots in the code faster. Here, we clearly have a dead store (`iinc` followed by `istore_1`), so... And who knows, perhaps it could even turn the whole thing into a no-op, since that's what it is.

Comment: may be. I have a feeling that the latest hot spots are *this* smart :).. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

```
int b = 0, c;
c = b++;
c = b++;
c = b++;
c = b++;
System.out.println(c);
```

`c` now will be 3 like you thought, but because in your question you're assigning `b`, it'll get 0, because as already explained, it's the same as:

```
int tmp = b;
b = b + 1;
b = tmp;
```

Answer (score 1):

`b++` is the same as:

```
int temp = b;
b = b + 1;
return temp;
```

As you can see `b++` will return his old value, but overwrites the value of `b`. But since you assign the returned (old) value to `b`, the new value will be overwritten and therefore "ignored".

A difference would be, if you write:

```
b = ++b; //exactly the same as just "++b"
```

This does the incrementation first and the new value will be returned.