# Post Increment and assigning to same variable

Tags: java

```
int b = 2;

c= b++;
System.out.Println("C :"+c+"B"+b);
```

`c` will be 2 and `b` will be 3.

```
int b = 2;

b= b++;
System.out.Println("B:"+b);
```

Here I wonder what is getting incremented. and where does that incremented value goes.

Comment: Since it's `b++`, the `b` is getting incremented after the statement is "processed", and the value goes to wherever specified; in these examples it doesn't go anywhere else.

Comment: The important thing here is that `b++` is the same thing as `b = b + 1`.

Comment: Since my previous answer was wrong. I will just link the better explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27621242/difference-between-b-b-and-b

Answer (score 4):

Well this is tricky. Let's take a look what the post-increment operator does. The [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.14.2) states:

> The value of the postfix increment expression is the value of the variable before the new value is stored.

So in your code `b++` has the value `2`, independently from the incrementation of `b`.

If you do an assignment, the right-hand side expression is evaluated first and then its value is stored into the variable.

It's straightforward if you do `c = b++`. The expression `b++` has the value `2` which gets assigned to `c`. After that statement `b` has the incremented value `3`. But that's a little simplified. What actually happens is, that `b++` is evaluated first, meaning `b` is incremented **before** the assignment takes place, not after.

So what happens when you do `b = b++`? Well, it's just the same: The `b++` is evaluated first, meaning `b` is incremented. After that the assignment takes place and the **value of the expression `b++`** is assigned to `b`. This is still `2` and overwrites your incremented `b`.

Fun fact: If I enter your second code in my Eclipse, [Findbugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/) issues the following warning:

> **Bug**: Overwritten increment in MyClass.main(String[])
>
> The code performs an increment operation (e.g., i++) and then immediately overwrites it. For example, i = i++ immediately overwrites the incremented value with the original value.

Comment: Well, it is not even fun that Eclipse needs a plugin to find out that the increment isn't used and therefore redundant. But that's just Eclipse :/.

Comment: @Tom Do you know an IDE that would have warned about this out of the box? (Disclaimer: Honest question, not trying to start an IDE war :D)

Comment: IntelliJ Idea does that. It has a full set of inspections and unused assignments (like `String s = "A"; s = "B";` or `i = i++;`) is one of them.

Comment: @Tom that's nice. Eclipse does show a few such things but not this particular case. I always go with Findbugs anyway since it finds a lot of not so obvious things.

Comment: And it is a good thing that Eclipse supports such Plugins and they definitely should be used, but I would prefer some more core features already implemented into Eclipse. But that's just a matter of taste. Plugins still can provide the same features.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you just don't get what happens here:

```
int b = 2;

b= b++;
System.out.println("B:"+b);
```

And more specifically, this line:

```
b = b++;
```

The compiler sees that this is an assignment statement, so it tries to evaluate the expression on the right first:

```
b++
```

Since `++` here is a post increment operator, the expression just evaluates to `b`, i.e. 2. Immediately after the evaluation, `b` is incremented to 3.

We're not done yet! This is an assignment statement remember? Now that the right side is evaluated, the expression now looks like this:

```
b = 2;
```

Great! Now `b` is assigned the value of `2`.

Answer (score 1):

```
int b=2    
b = b++
```

Is like you are running this code

```
int b = 2;
int temp = b;
b = b + 1;
b = temp;
```